# Which of the jar will be loaded in the JVM?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, classloader

So suppose I have a jar with a different version in the `ext` folder and the other version is in the `classpath`. Which version the the jar will be loaded? As per my research, since the `extension classloader` runs before the `classpath` one so the library in the extension will be loaded. Or will it be overriding with the `classpath` one. And what will happen if the version are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use the first class that it can find in the `ClassLoader`'s hierarchy.

So it will try to get the class from the next sequence of `ClassLoader`s:

1. The **Bootstrap `ClassLoader`** composed of the **Bootstrap classes** (the `rt.jar` and several other important `jar` files in `jre/lib`).
2. The **Extension `ClassLoader`** composed of the **Extension classes** (`jar` files in the extension folder `jre/lib/ext`).
3. The **System `ClassLoader`** composed of the **User classes** (the classes located in the classpath defined).

So as your class is not defined in #1 but in #2 and #3, the first class that it can find will be in #2, so it will get the version of the extension folder and simply ignore the one defined later in your classpath.

See also [**How Classes are Found**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html)

Answer (score 1):

It will be the class level not the Jar level. If the class (fully qualified class name) is already loaded to the vm then the new class in the ext or the class path libs class will be ignored.